# How do I keep an ID in a pandas DF that has duplicates only if all of its records in another column have the same value?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicates

I want to keep the research ID if all of the test grades are the same, but if not I cannot rely on the integrity of the data and must discard the ID.

I tried creating a dictionary, but for the research id below, only L4 was saved as a value.

```
ResearchID  TestGrade   
1026379     L4  
1026379     L2
1026379     L4
1026379     L4  
1026379     L4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) the research id and then keep only those ids where the length of the [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) test grades is equal to 1, using [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter).

```
df.groupby('ResearchID').filter(lambda g: len(g.TestGrade.unique()) == 1)
```

Comment: Or, `df.groupby('ResearchID').filter(lambda g: g.TestGrade.nunique() == 1)`